# Simulator works fine with using com.obsecure.keychain module of ios but device shows module error in titanium 3.2.2.GA iphone App

Tags: javascript, ios, module, titanium, should.js

I am developing iPhone app on **Titanium studio 3.2.2.GA** and integrated the **com.obsecure.keychain** to save the the login data. its works fine and no issue with the simulator. but when i tried to check the same app in device its showing the error that com.obsecure.keychain module not found.

I again googled for it and doesn't found any helpful link. Some links are suggesting to add the module in your project resource directory. I also tried this but again its showing the some syntax Error or unexpected token in should.js file (Which is inside the module). I tried to fix it by replacing the should.js file with another file should.js Master file  and become happy to find the same code without any syntax error. I copied and pasted it but this also showing the same bug as previously.

Please suggest how to fix this issue. (Again I want to mention that there is no issue while running the same app in simulator but all problem of module not found is with the device.)

Thanks in advance to all !!!

Comment: what is configuration of simulator & device?

Comment: I am using the ios sdk 7.0 and iphone ratina 4.0 inch (64 bit) for simulator and ios sdk 7.1 for ipod device.